# Problema con variable $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

Tengo esta función, en la cual no me reconoce la variable `$_SESSION['id_usuario']`, me la muestra como indefinida y la cuestión es que si existe, ya que la estoy usando en otras funciones.

```
public function mostrarImagenController($datos){

    list($ancho,$alto)=getimagesize($datos);

    if ($ancho < 1024 ||$alto < 768) {

        echo 0;

    }else{
        $aleatorio=mt_rand(100,999);
        $ruta="../../views/imagest/galeria/galeria".$aleatorio.".jpg";
        $nuevo_ancho=1024;
        $nuevo_alto=768;

        $origen=imagecreatefromjpeg($datos);

        #imagecreatetruecolor — Crear una nueva imagen de color verdadero
        $destino=imagecreatetruecolor($nuevo_ancho, $nuevo_alto);

        #imagecopyresized() - copia una porción de una imagen a otra imagen. 

        #bool imagecopyresized( $destino, $origen, int $destino_x, int $destino_y, int $origen_x, int $origen_y, int $destino_w, int $destino_h, int $origen_w, int $origen_h)

        imagecopyresized($destino, $origen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nuevo_ancho, $nuevo_alto, $ancho, $alto);

        imagejpeg($destino,$ruta);

        $id_tienda5=$_SESSION['id_usuario'];
        $datosController=array("ruta"=>$ruta,
                                "id"=>$id_tienda5);

        DatosTienda::subirImagengaleriaModel($datosController,"tiendas_cafe");
        $respuesta=DatosTienda::mostrarImagengaleriaModel($datosController,"tiendas_cafe");

        echo $respuesta['img_galeria_tienda'];

    }

}
```

Comment: Tienes [`session_start();`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php) incluido?

Comment: Si, en ese mismo archivo estoy usando esa variable de $_SESSION en otras funciones

Comment: En el fichero donde llamas a la función, ahí haces una llamada a `session_start()` ??

Comment: No el session_start() lo llamo desde el template

Answer (score 2):

por lo que estoy mirando el código, en ningún momento estas llamando a session_star(), o no la estas incluyendo, a menos que dentro del documento php en el encabezado este

```
<?php
session_start();
public function mostrarImagenController($datos){.....
```

lo otro que puede ser es que la session tenga otro nombre.

Comment: En ese mismo archivo tengo varias funciones y utilizo la variable session sin problemas, ya el session_start() esta incluido

Comment: Primero realiza un echo para ver si la session esta recibiendo algun parametro echo $_SESSION['id_usuario']; exit(); con eso veremos si llega algun dato para ver si es pasado al array a posterior.